# MongoDB - Find first and last in the embedded array for a single matching document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of websites, which each contain a list of websites and their keywords that are being tracked. I also have another collection called "rankings" which for each of the keywords in the website contains a ranking. The collection so far looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58503934034b512b419a6eab"),
    "website" : "https://www.google.com",
    "name" : "Google",
    "keywords" : [ 
        "Search", 
        "Websites", 
    ],
    "tracking" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5874aa1df63258286528598d"),
            "position" : 0,
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-1T09:32:13.831Z"),
            "real_url" : "https://www.google.com",
            "keyword" : "Search"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5874aa1ff63258286528598e"),
            "keyword" : "Search",
            "real_url" : "https://www.google.com",
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-2T09:32:15.832Z"),
            "found_url" : "https://google.com/",
            "position" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5874aa21f63258286528598f"),
            "keyword" : "Search",
            "real_url" : "https://www.foamymedia.com",
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-3T09:32:17.017Z"),
            "found_url" : "https://google.com/",
            "position" : 2
        }, 

        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5874aa21f63258286528532f"),
            "keyword" : "Websites",
            "real_url" : "https://www.google.com",
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-1T09:32:17.017Z"),
            "found_url" : "https://google.com/",
            "position" : 1
        }, 

         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5874aa21f63258286528542f"),
            "keyword" : "Websites",
            "real_url" : "https://www.google.com",
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-1T09:32:17.017Z"),
            "found_url" : "https://google.com/",
            "position" : 2
        }, 

    ]
}
```

What I want to do is:

1) Group all of the keywords together by their keyword

2) Find the starting position (at the very start of the month)

3) Find the current position (as of today)

So in theory I want to be given an object like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58503934034b512b419a6eab"), 
    "website" : "https://www.google.com",

    "tracking" : [
       {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5874aa1df63258286528598d"), 
           "keyword": "Search",
           "start_position": 0, 
           "todays_position": 3, 

       }, 

        {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5874aa1df63258286528598d"), 
           "keyword": "Website",
           "start_position": 0, 
           "todays_position": 2, 

       }, 


    ]
```

I am confused about how to do the grouping on another field, though. I have tried the following so far:

```
db.getCollection('websites').aggregate([

    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "seo_tracking", 
            localField: "website",
            foreignField: "real_url",
            as: "tracking"
        }
    },

    {
        $match: {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58503934034b512b419a6eab")
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            "_id" : "$_id", 
            "keyword" : {
                $first: "$tracking.keyword",
            },
        }
    }

]);
```

But this is not grouping by the keyword, nor can I figure out how I would get the expected value.

Comment: what do you have in second collection?

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy Thanks for the reply. The other collection contains everything inside the `tracking` in the first output. I have used aggregate to combine the two

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I already know the keywords and rankings.. The issue is that they are repeated, because data is collected throughout the month.. I just need to capture, foreach of the keywords, display the position at the start of the month and the position at todays date -- Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. `$unwind` the tracking array followed by `$sort` on `tracking.keyword` and `tracking.created_at`. `$group` by `tracking.keyword` and `$first` to get starting position,  `$avg` to get average position and `$last` to get the today's position. Final `$group` to roll up everything back to `tracking` array.

```
db.website.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "_id": ObjectId("58503934034b512b419a6eab")
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "seo_tracking",
        localField: "website",
        foreignField: "real_url",
        as: "tracking"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$tracking"
}, {
    $sort: {
        "tracking.keyword": 1,
        "tracking.created_at": -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$tracking.keyword",
        "website": {
            $first: "$website"
        },
        "website_id": {
            $first: "$_id"
        },
        "avg_position": {
            $avg: "$tracking.position"
        },
        "start_position": {
            $first: "$tracking.position"
        },
        "todays_position": {
            $last: "$tracking.position"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$website_id",
        "website": {
            $first: "$website"
        },
        "tracking": {
            $push: {
                "keyword": "$_id",
                "avg_position":"$avg_position",
                "start_position": "$start_position",
                "todays_position": "$todays_position"
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. This seems to have done the trick. One thing I'm getting confused with is the `$group` so let's say that keywords are tracked throughout the month... I wanted to get a average position of all of the keywords for all of that month (I will end up with 30 or so values).. Can I use something similar? For example, is `$group` grouping them all together?

Comment: Add the avg position to the answer to the first group. Updated answer.

Comment: No, I mean, basically, let's say you have 3 keywords, `Testing`, `SEO`, `Google` each of these get's searched every day.. What I'm asking is would I use a similar query to get what the total average of all of these keywords over a 30 day period for each of the days. So essentially, I would end up with 30 averages or however many days there are this month

Comment: Yes, lookup the searched keywords first and group by day and calculate average.

Comment: Thanks. However, `$group { "day" : "$tracking.created_at" }` gives me an error: `The field 'day' must be an accumulator object` shall i update with my query?

Comment: All the fields other than `_id` should use some kind of operator to be part of group stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132802/discussion-between-phorce-and-sagar-reddy).